# Using TPL Dataflow, how to compose workflow with BatchBlock in the middle and back out to individual item block?

Tags: task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

The idea is to process a list of items, individually and then batch up and then go back to processing individually seamlessly.
In the batch processing block, I may be querying or saving to the database. Hitting the DB with a batch is a lot more efficient than hitting it multiple times per each item in the list.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace DataflowTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var execOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded };
            var block1 = new TransformBlock<WorkItem, WorkItem>(async item =>
            {
                // perform work on individual item
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"Block 1 - Item {item.Id}");
                return item;
            }, execOptions);
            var block2 = new TransformBlock<WorkItem, WorkItem>(async item =>
            {
                // perform more work on individual item
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"Block 2 - Item {item.Id}");
                return item;
            }, execOptions);
            var batch = new BatchBlock<WorkItem>(5);
            var batchWork = new ActionBlock<WorkItem[]>(async items =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"batchWork - {items.Length} Items");
                // perform batch work - query database, etc.
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(x => block2.SendAsync(x)));
            }, execOptions);
            var batch2 = new BatchBlock<WorkItem>(10);
            var save = new ActionBlock<WorkItem[]>(async items =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"save - {items.Length} Items");
                // save items to the DB
                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }, execOptions);

            var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
            block1.LinkTo(batch, linkOptions);
            batch.LinkTo(batchWork, linkOptions);
            block2.LinkTo(batch2, linkOptions);
            batch2.LinkTo(save, linkOptions);

            Console.WriteLine("Starting work");
            var workItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new WorkItem { Id = x }).ToArray();
            await Task.WhenAll(workItems.Select(x => block1.SendAsync(x)));
            block1.Complete();
            await batchWork.Completion;

            block2.Complete();
            await save.Completion;

            Console.WriteLine("All Done");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class WorkItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I am looking for some feedback. Basically the above code sample seems to work.
The critical piece of code is within "batchWork" where I am queueing up to "block2" by calling SendAsync on each item. I don't know of a way to link up any other way. Perhaps there is a better approach to what I am trying to accomplish here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the point of `BatchWork`? You can use a `BatchBlock` directly to batch N items. If it does anything other than batching, it really shouldn't be called `BatchWork`. It shouldn't be an `ActionBlock` either, it should be a `TranformBlock` or `TransformManyBlock`

Comment: The answer of Panagiotis is correct. As a side note, I hope this ==> `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded` won't end up in your production code. It's very rare to want to run everything concurrently, without any limitation whatsoever. Also this code ==> `await Task.WhenAll(workItems.Select(x => block1.SendAsync(x)))` is highly suspect. The whole purpose of using the `SendAsync` instead of the `Post` is for blocking the producer (also known as *backpressure*). To make this happen you must `await` one `SendAsync` at a time, sequentially.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Unbounded value is something that I am playing with. Most examples that I have seen use Environment.ProcessorCount for example and that seems reasonable. In my testing however, even with Unbounded value, it never seems to go out of control and create 100s and 100s of threads for example. Have you experienced or seen an example of such a case?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Regarding the use of Task.WhenAll... thanks for pointing that out. In the context of my application, I will always have a limited number of items such as 100, no more than 400 for example. And most of my blocks will be CPU bound, except for where I am batching for I/O. Would that change anything? Still what you are suggesting seems valid. I don't think there is any gain in using Task.WhenAll here.

Comment: To see the effect of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded` in all its glory, you should make sure that you are not throttled by the `ThreadPool` availability. Just for fun you can put this at the start of your program: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000)`. This won't create preemptively 1000 threads, but will make sure that all requests for `ThreadPool` work will be instantly satisfied. New threads will be created immediately upon demand, until they reach the number of 1000.

Comment: Regarding the use of `SendAsync` in combination with the `BoundedCapacity` option, they are intended for scenarios where the number of messages passed form block to block is huge, and could lead to unreasonably high RAM utilization if it was left unconstrained. In your case the number of messages is pretty small, and there is no reason to incur the added complexity of backpressure. My suggestion is to use `Post` instead of `SendAsync` everywhere you send manually messages to blocks, and make sure that there is no `BoundedCapacity` forgotten anywhere (otherwise you may lose messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `SendAsync`. You can change `batchWork` to a `TransformManyBlock` and connect it to the next block:

```
var batchWork = new TransformManyBlock<WorkItem[],WorkItem>(async items =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"batchWork - {items.Length} Items");
    // perform batch work - query database, etc.
    
    return items;
}, execOptions);

....

batch.LinkTo(batchWork, linkOptions);
batchWork.LinkTo(block2, linkOptions);
block2.LinkTo(batch2, linkOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks - TransformManyBlock was exactly what I needed